# Did Arjuna kill 10 Kauravas?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, kauravas, bhima

It was Bhima's vow to kill all sons of Dhritarastra. We have seen Pandavas injuring them but not killing--leaving them to Bhima to kill. However in [Karna parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08080.htm) it says:

> He was then surrounded by ten heroic and foremost of warriors, viz., **thy sons, all of whom were Duhshasana's juniors in age**.
> ...
> Then with some broad-headed arrows he cut off and felled their heads decked with lips bit and eyes blood-red in rage.

Does it mean Arjuna killed 10 and not Bhima?

Comment: did Vyasa maintain the correct kill-count of kauravas are all killed kauravas named?  @shebbar ?

Comment: Don't know. I haven't kept count of the killings!

Comment: I am sure Sanjaya kept relating to Dhritarashtra the current body count of this sons as the war went on.  If Vyasa overlooked these 10 - that would be a gaffe @SHebbar

Comment: Perhaps there was no such oath taken by Bhima

Comment: There are references to Bhima's vow. Arjuna came very close to killing Dussasana but decided not too kill thinking about Bhima's vow. But the onev paragraph in the question here is anomaly. Only way to do is read all over again 800+pages and keep count of heads rolling!

Comment: I mean did you find reference to Bhima's vow ? I could not find it in version uploaded in sacred-text